# Raising Test Code Coverage on a Trigger that Counts Attachments

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, case, attachment

I have utilized the code from Sunil Sharma's blog here for a trigger to count attachments on a record. The only change that I have made here is that I have used "Case" instead of "TestObject__c."

The code in full and explanation can be found here: http://techysunil.blogspot.com/2015/04/trigger-to-count-number-of-attachments.html

I am writing a test class for this trigger, and have only been able to get it up to 64% test coverage so far:

```
@isTest
public class UpdateCaseNumberAttachment_Test {

   static testmethod void testAttachmentCounter(){

    String blobhello = 'Hello';
    Blob hello = blob.valueOf(blobhello);    

    Test.startTest();

    Account acc1 = New Account(Name = 'acc1');
    insert acc1;

    Case case1 = new Case(Origin = 'Test Class', Protocol_Sub_Issue__c ='Test Sub Issue');
    insert case1;

    Attachment att1 = New Attachment(Name = 'att1', parentId = case1.Id, Body = hello);
    insert att1;

    Case newQueriedCase = [SELECT Id, CountAttachment__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :case1.Id];    

    System.assertEquals(newQueriedCase.CountAttachment__c, 1);

    Test.stopTest();


}

}
```

The lines in the code that I am not able to get coverage for are the statemeents after "else if." The first "if" parts of the trigger seem to be covered fine by the code that I have here. I have tried writing asserts for when the attachment does not have a parent Id, but coverage remains at 64%. Have I missed something else that needs to have asserts written for it? The test class passes, but I would much rather have code coverage as close to 100 as possible.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). If you can do it declaratively, you should  do so. Not needing to write unit tests is a side benefit (though you should still functionally test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this version of the trigger:

```
trigger countAttachments on Attachment (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    Map<Id, Integer> parentCount = new Map<Id, Integer>();
    for(Attachment[] records: new List<Attachment[]> { Trigger.old, Trigger.new }) {
        if(records != null) {
            for(Attachment record: records) {
                if(record.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType) {
                    parentCount.put(record.ParentId, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(!parentCount.isEmpty()) {
        Case[] cases = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id IN :parentCount.keySet() FOR UPDATE];
        for(AggregateResult result:[SELECT ParentId Id, COUNT(Id) Total FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN :cases GROUP BY ParentId]) {
            parentCount.put((Id)result.get('Id'), ((Decimal)result.get('Total')).intValue());
        }
        for(Case record: cases) {
            record.CountAttachment__c = parentCount.get(record.Id);
        }
        update cases;
    }
}
```

Your unit test should get 100% coverage this way. Often times, it's more about how the *code* is written, not how the *test* is written. In this case, your test is correct, but your trigger was not as optimized as it could have been.